# PHP list issue ( Undefined offset: )

Tags: php, list

Original SQL query is this;
SELECT id,post_title,post_date FROM wp_posts where id='1'

When I retrieve the record, I am finding it but when it comes to returning the results, I am puzzled. Here is the where I got stuck.

```
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($RS)) :
      print_r ($row); 
      list($id,$post_title,$post_date) = $row;
   endwhile;
```

print_r ($row) outputs this; 
    Array ( [ID] => 1 [post_title] => Hello world! [post_date] => 2012-03-27 03:28:27 )

And when I run the list function in there ( for debug purposes obviously ), I get this;

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in F:\inetpub\wwwroot\whatever\sql.php on line 147
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in F:\inetpub\wwwroot\whatever\sql.php on line 147
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in F:\inetpub\wwwroot\whatever\sql.php on line 147
```

What's causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

`mysql_fetch_assoc($RS)`

with:

`mysql_fetch_array($RS, MYSQL_NUM)`

then it should work, because the `list` function trys to access the array using numeric keys.

Answer (score 6):

I guess the answer lies somewhere within this;

list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.

:(

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use `extract()` here instead, as well; ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).)

Answer (score 1):

You used mysql_fetch_assoc, so the resulting array per row has data under a key by column name, whereas "list" tries to match variables to values using numerical array indexes. You can use mysql_fetch_array instead.

Answer (score 0):

$categ = val1 | val2

list($one,$two,$three)=@split('[|]',$categ);

If you try to list the value which is not available it will return the error Undefined Offset.

Here the error will be Undefined Offset 2.

Because while spliting $categ, it will have only two values, if you try to access third value then it will return error.