# Foreach undefined offset error with $_POST and multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Here's my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['editbutton']))
        {
            UNSET ($_POST['editbutton']);
        foreach ($_POST as list ($id, $payment,$date)){
        echo $id;
        echo $payment;
        echo $date;}
        // $sqlupdate = ("UPDATE payments SET payment=:payment,payment_date=:date WHERE pay_id=:id");
        // $preparedStatement = $db->prepare($sqlupdate);
        }
```

I have my UPDATE commented out for now, just trying to get past this error. The echo's are also just for testing right now. Here's my var_dump of $_POST:

```
 array (size=3)
  'id' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '66' (length=2)
      1 => string '61' (length=2)
  'payment' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '67.00' (length=5)
      1 => string '125.00' (length=6)
  'date' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2015-07-19' (length=10)
      1 => string '2015-07-15' (length=10)
```

So, I have exactly what I want in $_POST, but it's foreach that isn't behaving in the way I'm expecting it to. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\foo on line 98
```

and of course line 98 is:

```
foreach ($_POST as list ($id, $payment,$date))
```

So, what am I not understanding about foreach? Since it's a foreach, once it reaches the end, it should stop, but it seems it's foreaching one extra time. Ideas? Suggestions?

And I think what I'm trying to do is pretty plain (to me at least) but I'll explain. I have a form that allows me to update multiple rows all at once. It submits them as $_POST['ID'], $_POST['payment'] and $_POST['pay_date']. My var_dump shows I'm getting exactly what I'm needing from the form. However, when I try and build my query I'm having issue getting the correct values from the arrays. What I want to do is get the [0] position out of each array, and throw them into my prepared query, run the update query, then start again with the [1] values of each array, run the update, rinse repeat.

---

EDIT: I got a perfectly working answer to my question, here is my working code.

```
 if (isset($_POST['editbutton']))
    {
      UNSET ($_POST['editbutton']);
      $sqlupdate = ("UPDATE payments SET payment=:payment, payment_date=:date WHERE pay_id=:id");
      $preparedStatement = $db->prepare($sqlupdate);
      list($id, $payment, $date) = array_values($_POST);
      foreach ($id as $key => $items)
         {
           $preparedStatement->execute(array(':payment' => $payment[$key], ':date' => $date[$key], ':id' => $items));
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, list() will not work with associative array and multidimensional array as we expect it. you can have reference here: [PHP list issue ( Undefined offset: )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900035/php-list-issue-undefined-offset#9900056)

However, if you want to use list() anyhow you can use it like this:

```
list($id, $payment, $date) = array_values($_POST);
foreach ($id as $key => $items) {
    echo $items;
    echo $payment[$key];
    echo $date[$key];
}
```

you can use other variations instead foreach as you want.

Comment: From what I read in your link, list() tries to work on numerical arrays, and doesn't work well on associative arrays, like you said. I had read that somewhere else, so I used a foreach ($P_POST as $editinfo[]) {}, and when I var_dumped $editinfo it had taken out the "names" and instead created a numerical array. But I still got the same error when I ran a foreach ($editinfo as list($id,$payment,$pay_date)). So I'm going to play around with your suggesting above and see what I can do with it. Thanks!

Comment: I've read about using the foreach like you showed above, but I'm not understanding 100% how it works, I'm going to throw it in my code and dump the variables until I do. I also updated my question with some stuff I realized after I wrote my question, and clarifying what I was wanting to do. Thanks so much for the suggestions so far!

Comment: Perfect! This worked exactly like what I wanted! I'm not sure exactly what it's doing :(, I'm going to stare at it and hope it starts making more sense to me. But it did just what I was needing, without having to use for loops and counting iterations and all that. Thanks so much! I didn't even know you could use LIST in this format, I had never seen it anywhere before. This is great info!

Comment: ok, I've spent all night dumping the variables and looking at this code, and I still don't understand how this is working. I don't get how the list, nor the foreach is getting the results it is. It works, but I just don't get it. Anyone got any links that could explain what's going on here for dummies? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`UNSET` will reset you `$_POST` values. So use it after your Job is done

[Example is here](http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/unset.php)

```
<?php
    $xyz='w3resource.com';
    echo 'Before using unset() the value of $xys is : '. $xyz.'<br>';
    unset($xyz);
    echo 'After using unset() the value of $xys is : '. $xyz;
?>
```

**Output**:

```
Before using unset() the value of $xys is : w3resource.com
After using unset() the value of $xys is :
```

So Final well form code is

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['editbutton']))
{
    foreach ($_POST as list ($id, $payment,$date))
    {
        echo $id;
        echo $payment;
        echo $date;
    }
    //unset after doing the job
    UNSET ($_POST['editbutton']);
}
```

Comment: I was unsetting the [editbutton] part of the array, not all of $_POST. Till I did that it was trying to put the name of the input tag of the editbutton into the output of the foreach. By unsetting it, it solved that problem, at least.

Comment: It solved my problem of the [editbutton] array value getting into my foreach, that's what I had the unset there for, and it solved the problem I added it to fix. My problem I posted my question about is not fixed, but I have not had a chance to try the below suggestion yet. I will shortly.

Answer (score -1):

You are not getting the correct values.

Try to add:

```
echo 'id is ' .$id;
echo 'payment is '.$payment;
echo 'date is..well not valid ' .$date;
```

And maybe you will learn something by also understand what the prev answer told you.

Comment: Yeah, after I wrote my question, I took a shower, and had one of those great shower time realizations. Most of my great ideas happen in the shower! LOL I wasn't getting the output I expected, I was getting all of [id] dumped into $id, then all of [payment] dumped into $payment, and so on. Not just the first value of each array. foreach is just not behaving the way I expected it to. Thanks.

Comment: well:P i have worked with php for about 3 years and i never use list when looping through data. I think that if you didnt use list() foreach will seem a lot more understandable